# Add 3D-helpful axes on the side matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, 3d, axes

I have been plotting 3D scatter plots from experimental data. It represents the contour of an ellipsoid-like object. The size and shape of the ellipsoid varies with the sample.

This is the reason why I want to save the scatter plot as 2D projections of my data, along (xOy), (xOz), and (yOz) planes (and probably others). 
For clarity, I was wondering how can I also draw the axes onto which I am projecting, on the side of the plot (just like molecular visualisation softwares can do). 
I made an example by adding the axes roughly with Inkscape, but I would like a solution using matplotlib if possible.

See the following example image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another axes to the figure, located in the lower left corner, e.g.

```
xax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1,0.2, 0.2])
```

and plot some annotations with arrows to it.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

xax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1,0.2, 0.2])

xax.annotate('', xy=(1, 0), xytext=(0, 0),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.02), clip_on=False)
xax.annotate('x', xy=(1.1, 0), clip_on=False, va="center")
xax.annotate('', xy=(0, 1), xytext=(0, 0),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.02), clip_on=False)
xax.annotate('y', xy=(0, 1.1), clip_on=False, ha="center")
xax.set_xlim(-.2,1.5)
xax.set_ylim(-.2,1.5)
xax.set_aspect("equal")
xax.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

[image]

This is of course not synchronized with the 3D axes, so you may produce one of such axes per view you want to save.

Comment: Superb! Exactly what I was looking for. The non-synchronisation is not an issue as my request was destined for final views, so I will do exactly as suggested. 

Thanks so much